# "Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" when installing pycurl

Tags: python, installation, pycurl

I'm trying to install pycurl via:

```
sudo pip install pycurl
```

It downloaded fine, but when when it runs setup.py I get the following traceback:

```
Downloading/unpacking pycurl
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pycurl
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-root/pycurl/setup.py", line 563, in <module>
        ext = get_extension()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-root/pycurl/setup.py", line 368, in get_extension
        ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-root/pycurl/setup.py", line 65, in __init__
        self.configure()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-root/pycurl/setup.py", line 100, in configure_unix
        raise ConfigurationError(msg)
    __main__.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/pycurl/setup.py", line 563, in <module>

    ext = get_extension()

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/pycurl/setup.py", line 368, in get_extension

    ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration()

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/pycurl/setup.py", line 65, in __init__

    self.configure()

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/pycurl/setup.py", line 100, in configure_unix

    raise ConfigurationError(msg)

__main__.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any idea why this is happening and how to get around it

Comment: are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm on OSX with an ssh connection to a linux terminal

Comment: where are you trying to install pycurl?

Answer (score 663, accepted):

On Debian I needed the following packages to fix this

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

Comment: That fixed my issue on Ubuntu 12.04 (x64) and Python3.4 installed

Comment: Thanks, I needed the `libssl-dev` package in addition to yours. Strange how `pip` decouples from system package management but doesn't even give hints about which package it could be I'm missing on a very common linux distribution.

Comment: I need both libcurl4-openssl-dev and libssl-dev on Debian 9: sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: @JohnMcGehee, yep, works on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on WSL too.

Comment: be careful, `libssl-dev` is not compatible with `npm` rightnow

Comment: any windows guy?

Comment: Works on Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS / Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 89):

Similarly with `yum` package manager

```
yum install libcurl-devel
```

If you use `dnf`, use

```
dnf install libcurl-devel
```

Comment: In my case python-devel was missing as well, so the following solved the issue for me:
yum install libcurl-devel python-devel

Comment: Yup. Just `apt install   libcurl4-openssl-dev`   on an Ubuntu 20.04 system. (nowhere else mentioned for this OS distro)

Answer (score 30):

in my case this fixed the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-dev
```

as explained [here](http://mattseymour.net/blog/2015/04/pip-install-pycurl-failed-with-exit-status-1/)

Comment: thanks for the python-dev package! i had this error without it : src/pycurl.h:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

Comment: A better link would be https://stackoverflow.com/a/31002176/733092, which explains that these are libraries of C headers needed to build C Python extensions on Linux.

Comment: Works for me in docker using ubuntu:focal

Answer (score 21):

In Alpine linux you should do:

```
apk add curl-dev python3-dev libressl-dev
```

Comment: `apk add curl-dev` was enough for me in docker `python2.7-alpine` image, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Same solution provided by @Michael Rice works for Ubuntu 18.04 as well

#### Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

Al thought it is mentioned in comments of Michael's answer but thought highlight for easy of use.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem whilst trying to get Shinken 2.0.3 to fire up on Ubuntu. Eventually I did a full uninstall then reinstalled Shinken with `pip -v`. As it cleaned up, it mentioned:

> `Warning: missing python-pycurl lib, you MUST install it before launch the shinken daemons`

Installed that with `apt-get`, and all the brokers fired up as expected :-)

Answer (score 2):

That solved my problem on Ubuntu 14.04:

> apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev

Answer (score 2):

If the following **solution** giving you an error while installing them,

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

then try to update your Linux os first with:

```
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of [eldos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27795678/2528209) I also needed `gcc` in CentOS 7:

```
yum install libcurl-devel gcc
```

Comment: It was "yum install openssl-devel.x86_64 libcurl-devel.x86_64" for me on CentOS 8

Answer (score 0):

On OpenSUSE:

```
zypper in libcurl-devel
```

Comment: zypper in libcurl-devel libopenssl-devel

Answer (score 0):

In my case i kept getting the same error message. I use fedora.
I solved it by doing:

```
sudo dnf install pycurl
```

This installed eveything that I needed for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Mac and it was related to the `openssl` package being an older version of what it was required by `pycurl`. `pycurl` can use other ssl libraries rather than openssl as per my understanding of it. Verify which ssl library you're using and update as it is very likely to fix the issue.

I fixed this by:

- running `brew upgrade`
- downloaded the latest `pycurl-x.y.z.tar.gz` from
  http://pycurl.io/
- extracted the package above and change directory into it
- ran `python setup.py --with-openssl install` as openssl is the library I have installed. If you're ssl library is either `gnutls` or `nss` then will have to use `--with-gnutls` or `--with-nss` accordingly. You'll be able to find more [installation info in their github repository](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/blob/master/INSTALL.rst).

Answer (score 0):

Be advised that if you're using nodejs there's (at the time of writing) a dependency on libssl 1.0.* - so installing an alternative SSL library will break your nodejs installation.

An alternative solution to installing a different SSL library is that posted in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927568/13564342 to instead install libcurl4-gnutls-dev

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```