# What is python-dev package used for

Tags: python, header-files, cpython

I recently installed `lxml`.

Before that, I had to install all the dependencies for that.
So I tried to install `liblxml2-dev`, `liblxslt1-dev` and `python-dev`
(google-searched for what packages are required for `lxml`)
but even after that, I could not able to install `lxml` by using the command
`pip install lxml`.

However as because I am using Python 3.4.0, I thought that may be there are different version of `python-dev` (thought came due to facing some similar version conflict problem). So I tried to install `python3-dev`.

Then I tried to install `lxml` using the same command said earlier and that worked!!!

I google-searched for those sentences
and I could able to understand the meaning of `lxml` and `xslt`. I found a [link](https://packages.debian.org/sid/python-dev) for `python-dev` but I am not still sure what it is actually doing.

OS - Ubuntu

Comment: Different platforms have different conventions; the question should mention which OS you are on (I'm guessing Debian Linux or a derivative like Ubuntu or Mint, though RPM-based distros have a similar arrangement with a separate `-dev` package for headers).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

#### python-dev

`python-dev` contains the *header files* you need **to build *Python extensions***.

#### lxml

`lxml` is a **Python C-API extension** that is compiled when you do `pip install lxml`. The lxml sources have at least something like `#include <Python.h>` in the code. The compiler looks for the *header file* `Python.h` during compilation, hence those *header files* need to be on your system such that they can be found.

#### `-dev` packages on Linux

On Linux typically, the *binary libraries* and *header files* of packages like *Python* are separate. Hence you can have Python (e.g. package `python`) installed and everything works fine. But when you want to build *extensions* you need to install the corresponding `-dev` package.

Comment: You said when you want to build extensions you need to install the corresponding dev package. Can you please explain more on it?. How header files are building extensions

Comment: The header files are needed when you build the extension. The extension source code references header files of the libraries it uses. When the Python extension is built it uses the Python shared library that contains the   Python API C functions and data structures.

This applies not only to Python but to almost all libraries and applications you install on your system. Whenever you write a program that uses the librarie's API you need the corresponding devel package to build your program.

Comment: Yes, on Windows this is similar. Typically libraries provide SDK packages (zip or installers) which include the header files. When you build extensions for Python they often are compiled with the Visual Studio tools and the VS project files need to reference these header files.

Answer (score 20):

`python-dev` is the package that contains the header files for the Python C API, which is used by `lxml` because it includes Python C extensions for high performance.

Answer (score 7):

python-dev contains everything needed to compile python extension modules (https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).

Note that Debian already has an lxml package for python 3 (mentioned at http://lxml.de/installation.html); in general it's a good idea to use the packaged version. I'd suggest `pip uninstall lxml` and then `apt-get install python3-lxml`.