# Pyinstaller failing because pyconfig.h not found on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an executable from a Python script using PyInstaller, but I get the following error:

```
30391 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
Unable to find "\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\Include\pyconfig.h" when 
adding binary and data files.
```

I could only find instances of people having this problem on Linux, but I'm on Windows. I tried adding an empty file called pyconfig.h to the given file path. This allowed PyInstaller to complete, but the resulting `.exe` file only prints some text and immediately closes the console window.

I successfully created an executable from another script that uses all the same packages aside from pandas, so I believe that might be the problem.

I'm running PyInstaller through the system shell on Thonny. My OS is Windows 10 and my Python version is 3.6.4.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I managed to solve this by myself. Turns out it was a combination of several errors.

Creating an empty `pyconfig.h` file did solve the original problem.

Running the exe from the command line allowed me to see what the actual issue was. Turns out it was a missing hidden import from the pandas module.

I also forgot to include my data file and Chrome driver. All of these problems were fixed my editing the pyinstaller spec file:

```
a = Analysis(['script.py'],
         binaries=[('chromedriver.exe','.')],
         datas=[('data/datafile.xlsx','data')],
         hiddenimports=['pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas'],
         ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

`pyconfig.h` is part of the `python-dev` package. Installing `python-dev` can also fix your issue.

See this question to understand more about what `python-dev` is: [What is python-dev package used for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31002091/2038264)

Comment: What I have done is yank a similar pyconfig.h file from an installed Python. [Not the best practice...]