# Can't install Pip package on Raspberry PI 4 (adafruit_circuitpython_neopixel)

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to install the library above on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian Buster / RetroPi .

Setup collects packages, and then fails on `setup.py` stating:

```
* Setup can't determine the value of PAGE_SIZE on your system, so it will
    * default to 4096 which may not be correct.
```

More diagnostics/troubleshooting tried:

- I've installed the same package previously on a Raspberry Pi 3 without issue (Which I think was also running Buster)
- I've managed to install other python packages on the Pi 4 using `pip3 install` i.e. `tornado`, `colorzero` etc.
- I've run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` + rebooting- didn't help
- I've tried python 2 (`pip install pip install adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel`) - same error

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Full Error:

```
pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel
  Using cached adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel-6.0.3.tar.gz (28 kB)
Collecting Adafruit-Blinka
  Using cached Adafruit-Blinka-6.4.2.tar.gz (122 kB)
Collecting adafruit-circuitpython-pypixelbuf>=2.0.0
  Using cached adafruit-circuitpython-pypixelbuf-2.2.4.tar.gz (28 kB)
Collecting Adafruit-PlatformDetect>=3.1.0
  Using cached Adafruit-PlatformDetect-3.5.0.tar.gz (29 kB)
Collecting Adafruit-PureIO>=1.1.7
  Using cached Adafruit_PureIO-1.1.8.tar.gz (26 kB)
Collecting pyftdi>=0.40.0
  Using cached pyftdi-0.52.9-py3-none-any.whl (139 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: RPi.GPIO in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from Adafruit-Blinka->adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel) (0.7.0)
Collecting rpi_ws281x>=4.0.0
  Using cached rpi_ws281x-4.2.6.tar.gz (63 kB)
Collecting sysv_ipc>=1.1.0
  Using cached sysv_ipc-1.1.0.tar.gz (99 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyusb>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pyftdi>=0.40.0->Adafruit-Blinka->adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial>=3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pyftdi>=0.40.0->Adafruit-Blinka->adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel) (3.5)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for adafruit-circuitpython-pypixelbuf, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for Adafruit-Blinka, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for Adafruit-PlatformDetect, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for Adafruit-PureIO, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for rpi-ws281x, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for sysv-ipc, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: sysv-ipc, rpi-ws281x, pyftdi, Adafruit-PureIO, Adafruit-PlatformDetect, Adafruit-Blinka, adafruit-circuitpython-pypixelbuf, adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel
    Running setup.py install for sysv-ipc ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9qk3bog7/sysv-ipc_2c9b66fe81a04f5c99cf319aff553101/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9qk3bog7/sysv-ipc_2c9b66fe81a04f5c99cf319aff553101/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-d842td8m/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/pi/.local/include/python3.7m/sysv-ipc
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9qk3bog7/sysv-ipc_2c9b66fe81a04f5c99cf319aff553101/
    Complete output (19 lines):
    ******************************************************************************
    * Setup can't determine the value of PAGE_SIZE on your system, so it will
    * default to 4096 which may not be correct.
    *
    * Please report this message and your operating system info to the package
    * maintainer listed in the README file.
    ******************************************************************************
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'sysv_ipc' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c sysv_ipc_module.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7/sysv_ipc_module.o
    sysv_ipc_module.c:32:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9qk3bog7/sysv-ipc_2c9b66fe81a04f5c99cf319aff553101/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9qk3bog7/sysv-ipc_2c9b66fe81a04f5c99cf319aff553101/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-d842td8m/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/pi/.local/include/python3.7m/sysv-ipc Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Mods - I wasn't sure if this is more appropriate for the Rpi site, since it it's mainly about Python packages, but it might be specifc to Rpi. Feel free to move it if you see fit.

Comment: Full error traceback?

Comment: Right, forgot to attach it, sorry. Edited post to include it.

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install wheel` and then attempting to install again?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try `sudo apt install python3-dev` and then try installing again.

Comment: did you try `sudo pip3 install...`?

Comment: Wheel didn't work, but installing `python3-dev` did! :)
Thanks, If you'd like to post it as an answer I'll accept it.
Also if you'd be interested to expand I'd love to understand better why it was necessary for setup to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SuperStormer suggested `sudo apt install python3-dev` - which worked!

I have no idea why this works, as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002091/what-is-python-dev-package-used-for) suggests that its usage is for Python extensions and not regular libraries.

It apparently contains the Python C headers, so maybe the library needed those for some reason.

Comment: to build the library, it needed the C headers (since you need to build C programs, and python support C extensions). On Windows you get them with Visual Studio. On Linux you apparently get them with `sudo apt install python3-dev`. Learning new stuff everyday!

Comment: "Python extensions" means bits of libraries implemented in other languages (like C and C++) using the Python extension API: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html - if there isn't a wheel (pre-compiled) available for a package you need, then you have to compile from source (if available) - pip does the work for you, but you need to have python3-dev and any other build dependencies the package requires when building.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that pip uses **piwheels.org** as an additional index - piwheels builds pre-compiled wheels for all packages, so you don't have to compile them yourself.

Standard Raspberry Pi OS pre-configures pip to use it by adding `/etc/pip.conf` containing:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple
```

Alternatively, specify it in your pip command e.g:

```
pip3 install xxx --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple
```

You can read more and look at specific packages at [piwheels.org](https://www.piwheels.org/)