# Error when trying to install pycurl

Tags: python-2.7

I'm having an issue when running a python script, I'm getting below mentioned error

> "ImportError: No module named pycurl"

I tried to resolve this by trying this command "sudo pip install pycurl" and I got this error

> Downloading/unpacking pycurl   Downloading pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz
>   (182kB): 182kB downloaded   Running setup.py
>   (path:/tmp/pip-build-vqUn8V/pycurl/setup.py) egg_info for package
>   pycurl
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 17, in 
>         File "/tmp/pip-build-vqUn8V/pycurl/setup.py", line 823, in 
>           ext = get_extension(sys.argv, split_extension_source=split_extension_source)
>         File "/tmp/pip-build-vqUn8V/pycurl/setup.py", line 497, in get_extension
>           ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration(argv)
>         File "/tmp/pip-build-vqUn8V/pycurl/setup.py", line 71, in **init**
>           self.configure()
>         File "/tmp/pip-build-vqUn8V/pycurl/setup.py", line 107, in configure_unix
>           raise ConfigurationError(msg)
>       **main**.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 17, in
>
> File "/tmp/pip-build-vqUn8V/pycurl/setup.py", line 823, in
>
> ```
> ext = get_extension(sys.argv, split_extension_source=split_extension_source)
> ```
>
> File "/tmp/pip-build-vqUn8V/pycurl/setup.py", line 497, in
>   get_extension
>
> ```
> ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration(argv)
> ```
>
> File "/tmp/pip-build-vqUn8V/pycurl/setup.py", line 71, in **init**
>
> ```
> self.configure()
> ```
>
> File "/tmp/pip-build-vqUn8V/pycurl/setup.py", line 107, in
>   configure_unix
>
> ```
> raise ConfigurationError(msg)
> ```
>
> **main**.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

---

> Cleaning up...
>   Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vqUn8V/pycurl
>   Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

Comment: Looks like you need curl libs installed on the system. What OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Could not run curl-config: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory" when installing pycurl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937933/could-not-run-curl-config-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-when-installing)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Are you running Debian? It worked for me after installing the following packages:

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Also Ubuntu 18.04 (Docker image)