# while installing pycurl i got an error with this -->Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ZQIumo/pycurl/

Tags: python, pycurl

While installing pycurl I got this error:

```
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-ZQIumo/pycurl/setup.py) egg_info for package pycurl
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ZQIumo/pycurl/setup.py", line 823, in <module>
        ext = get_extension(sys.argv, split_extension_source=split_extension_source)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ZQIumo/pycurl/setup.py", line 497, in get_extension
        ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration(argv)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ZQIumo/pycurl/setup.py", line 71, in __init__
        self.configure()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ZQIumo/pycurl/setup.py", line 107, in configure_unix
        raise ConfigurationError(msg)
    __main__.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Cleaning up...
**Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ZQIumo/pycurl/**
Exception information:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Could not run curl-config: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory" when installing pycurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937933/could-not-run-curl-config-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-when-installing)

Comment: Thanks for the help.