# How do I install libcurl4-openssl-dev together with libssl1.0-dev?

Tags: openssl, ubuntu-18.04, curlpp

I need to use npm together with building C++ application using curl++. npm cannot be installed with libcurl4-openssl-dev on Ubuntu. If I use libcurl4-nss-dev instead of libcurl4-openssl-dev, my code compiles sucessfully, but gives error "No URL set!" in the same situation, when it worked correctly on libcurl4-openssl-dev. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a workaround: using **libcurl4-gnutls-dev** instead of libcurl4-nss-dev or libcurl4-openssl-dev.