# installing pyinstaller on python 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller

I'm trying to install `pyinstaller 3.5` in `python 3.4.3` but i get this error:

```
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\DTI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_dyh3r_g\pefile\
```

The command i use is this:

```
pip install pyinstaller==3.5
```

I'm using the latest version that `3.4.3` can use of pip, setuptools and wheel.

```
pip 19.1.1  
setuptools 43.0.0  
wheel 0.33.6
```

I appreciate all the help.

this is the full log:

```
pip install pyinstaller=="3.5"

DEPRECATION: Python 3.4 support has been deprecated. pip 19.1 will be the last one supporting it. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.4 won't be maintained after March 2019 (cf PEP 429).
Collecting pyinstaller==3.5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/c9/0b44b2ea87ba36395483a672fddd07e6a9cb2b8d3c4a28d7ae76c7e7e1e5/PyInstaller-3.5.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 (from pyinstaller==3.5)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/4b/3ab2720f1fa4b4bc924ef1932b842edf10007e4547ea8157b0b9fc78599a/pywin32_ctypes-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller==3.5) (43.0.0)
Collecting altgraph (from pyinstaller==3.5)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/3d/bfca21174b162f6ce674953f1b7a640c1498357fa6184776029557c25399/altgraph-0.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pefile>=2017.8.1 (from pyinstaller==3.5)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/1e/fc4fac0169d16a98577809400bbcfac8ad1900fa792184327b360ea51fc6/pefile-2021.5.13.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\DTI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3rgqa38b\pefile\setup.py", line 86, in <module>
        long_description = "\n".join(_read_doc().split('\n')),
      File "C:\Users\DTI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3rgqa38b\pefile\setup.py", line 33, in _read_doc
        tree = ast.parse(f.read())
      File "c:\python34\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
        return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
      File "<unknown>", line 3789
        f'Export directory contains more than 10 repeated entries '
                                                                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\DTI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3rgqa38b\pefile\
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/..../](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64095094/command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1-in-tmp)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do research first, like [`ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ERROR%3A%20Command%20%22python%20setup.py%20egg_info%22). Post links and describe gaps, if the answers found don't solve it.

Comment: the solution usually is to update but that did not solve my problem

Comment: The syntax error you an getting is because the Python 3.4 interpreter doesn't accept `f`-strings. I think you're making life unnecessarily difficult by insisting on using a Python version that reached end-of-life 4 years ago.

Comment: I need to run all of this on a Windows XP PC, so ... it's Python 3.4.3 or 2.7, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pefile` (one of the PyInstaller dependencies) [requires python >= 3.6.0](https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile/blob/master/setup.py#L89)

Comment: ok that helps a lot! I will try to install a compatible version of pefile.

Comment: That solve my problem, thank you a lot! i install pefile 2019.4.18 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install pyinstaller` This should work

or
If you wanted the specific version you can do that by
`pip install pyinstaller == "3.5"`

Comment: thanks for answering. I paste it and I get the same error.

Comment: what's the error your getting? also what's the OS you are using?

Comment: is this  `ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\DTI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_dyh3r_g\pefile\`

Comment: @Legalins try upgrading pip -> ```python -m pip install --upgrade pip```  after that install pyinstaller. If that doesn't work i'm not exactly sure. I tried installing pyinstaller and had no issue. Also check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1

Comment: I try to update and downgrade my pip and it didn't work